# Matrices with different row lengths in numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix, theano

Is there a way of defining a matrix (say *m*) in numpy with rows of different lengths, but such that *m* stays 2-dimensional (i.e. m.ndim = 2)?

For example, if you define *m = numpy.array([[1,2,3], [4,5]])*, then *m.ndim* = 1. I understand why this happens, but I'm interested if there is any way to trick numpy into viewing *m* as 2D. One idea would be padding with a dummy value so that rows become equally sized, but I have lots of such matrices and it would take up too much space. The reason why I really need *m* to be 2D is that I am working with Theano, and the tensor which will be given the value of *m* expects a 2D value.

Comment: I am a little confused. :-)  What are you actually trying to do? There might be a better way of going about your intent in Python/numpy.

Comment: Here is another question that I posted and that explains exactly what I'm trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205187/variable-length-tensors-in-theano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. NumPy arrays need to be rectangular in every pair of dimensions. This is due to the way they map onto memory buffers, as a pointer, itemsize, stride triple.

As for this taking up space: `np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5]])` actually takes up more space than a 2×3 array, because it's an array of two pointers to Python lists (and even if the elements were converted to arrays, the memory layout would still be inefficient).

Answer (score 2):

I'll give here very new information about Theano. We have a new TypedList() type, that allow to have python list with all elements with the same type: like 1d ndarray. All is done, except the documentation.

There is limited functionality you can do with them. But we did it to allow looping over the typed list with scan. It is not yet integrated with scan, but you can use it now like this:

```
import theano
import theano.typed_list

a = theano.typed_list.TypedListType(theano.tensor.fvector)()
s, _ = theano.scan(fn=lambda i, tl: tl[i].sum(),
                   non_sequences=[a],
                   sequences=[theano.tensor.arange(2, dtype='int64')])

f = theano.function([a], s)
f([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]])
```

One limitation is that the output of scan must be an ndarray, not a typed list.

Comment: What is the release that includes the typed_list module? I'm using Theano 6.0 (the latest release I can see on github) and it doesn't include it.

Comment: Use the development version.

Comment: I've been playing around with this and I came across the following question: Will this work when the argument function (fn) doesn't produce outputs with the same shape for all its inputs? For instance, consider fn=lambda i, tl: tl + t.constant(1). Then the outputs of fn have the same uneven lengths as the inputs, which means that theano.scan cannot pack them together into a theano.matrix. From my experiments, such cases fail. Is that right, or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: That is right. We haven't implemented ways to return typed list from Scan up to now.