# Typed Lists in Theano

Tags: theano, machine-translation

Consider the following machine translation problem. Let `s` be a source sentence and `t` be a target sentence. Both sentences are conceptually represented as lists of indices, where the indices correspond to the position of the words in the associated dictionaries. Example:

```
s = [34, 68, 91, 20]
t = [29, 0, 43]
```

Note that `s` and `t` don't necessarily have the same length. Now let `S` and `T` be sets of such instances. In other words, they are a parallel corpus. Example:

```
S = [[34, 68, 91, 20], [4, 7, 1]]
T = [[29, 0, 43], [190, 37, 25, 60]]
```

Note that not all `s`'s in `S` have the same length. That is, sentences have variable numbers of words.

I am implementing a machine translation system in Theano, and the first design decision is what kind of data structures to use for `S` and `T`. From one of the answers posted on [Matrices with different row lengths in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203451/matrices-with-different-row-lengths-in-numpy) , I learnt that typed lists are a good solution for storing variable length tensors.

However, I realise that they complicate my code a lot. Let me give you one example. Say that we have two typed lists `y` and `p_y_given_x` and aim to calculate the negative loss likelihood. If they were regular tensors, a simple statement like this would suffice:

```
loss = t.mean(t.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(p_y_given_x, y))
```

But `categorical_crossentropy` can only be applied to tensors, so in case of typed lists I have to iterate over them and apply the function separately to each element:

```
_loss, _ = theano.scan(fn=lambda i, p, y: t.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(p[i], y[i]),
                       non_sequences=[p_y_given_x, y],
                       sequences=[t.arange(y.__len__(), dtype='int64')])
loss = t.mean(_loss)
```

On top of making my code more and more messy, these problems propagate. For instance, if I want to calculate the gradient of the loss, the following doesn't work anymore:

```
grad_params = t.grad(loss, params)
```

I don't know exactly why it doesn't work. I'm sure it has to do with the type of `loss`, but I am not interested in investigating any further how I could make it work. The mess is growing exponentially, and what I would like is to know whether I am using typed lists in the wrong way, or if it is time to give up on them because they are not well enough supported yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typed list isn't used by anybody yet. But the idea for having them is that you iterate on them with scan for each sentence. Then you do everything you need in 1 scan. You don't do 1 scan for each operation.

So the scan is only used to do the iteration on each example in the minibatch, and the inside of scan is all what is done on one example.

We haven't tested typed list with grad yet. It is possible that it is missing some implementations.